# Behavior of 'reliable' publisher in case of unreachable subscriber

Tags: ros2, qos, rmw

Consider a ROS 2 publisher with QoS 'reliable' and a few subscribers.

Suddenly one of the subscribers can no longer be reached (e.g. it is running on a different system and the network cable is pulled out).

As it is a 'reliable' publisher, it will try to republish, but:

- When?
- At which frequency?
- For how long? (I.e. after what duration will it consider the subscriber as 'no longer subscribed'?)

I would assume the latter might be related to the 'liveliness' and 'lease duration', but the [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings.html#qos-policies) only mentions *publishers* and not *subscribers*.